# Leading space with STR function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to get a comma separated list with quotes and I'm almost at that point but I get a list with commas but a leading space at the start but in between the first quote and the string.

```
select stuff((select distinct ','+''''+str(bid)+'''' from dbo.Companies
where IdCompany in (select substring(ID_COMPANY,1,LEN(ID_COMPANY)-2)  from
sql.Companies where SEGMENT = @Segment and STATE = 'ACTIVE')
FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' )
```

I get something like this:

```
' 500004600',' 500005200',' 500009600',' 500021500'
```

How do I remove the left space so that I just get:

```
'500004600','500005200','500009600','500021500'
```

Comment: DDL and sample data would make this a lot easier to help. Does your data have a leading space?

Comment: Why are you using `str(bid)`? What is the data type of `bid`? Have you tried `LTRIM(bid)` instead? Also if these are integers, `QUOTENAME(LTRIM(bid), char(39))` is a lot tidier and easier on the eyes and brain than `'+'''''`… counting single quotes really sucks.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Also if you are using SQL Server 2017 or greater (always useful to actually specify), ditch FOR XML PATH and STUFF in favor of STRING_AGG. See https://sqlperformance.com/2022/02/t-sql-queries/string-aggregation-over-the-years-in-sql-server

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have? `select @@version`

Comment: It's SQL Server 2008

Comment: Yitzhak, it's just a column with codes. There's no need for more explanation. Anyone who's dealt with the stuff function knows what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the `STR()` function

> *length*
>
> Is the total length. This includes decimal point, sign, digits, and spaces. **The default is 10.**

You have not specified a value so it's spacing it out to 10.

You should instead `CAST` the number to `varchar`. An easier option, when you anyway have concatenation, is to use `CONCAT` which will cast it also.

> You should also remove the `DISTINCT` and use `GROUP BY bid`, otherwise indexes and other optimizations cannot be used (because of the concatenation).

```sql
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT CONCAT(',''', c.bid, '''')
    FROM dbo.Companies c
    WHERE c.IdCompany in (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(c2.ID_COMPANY, 1, LEN(c2.ID_COMPANY) - 2)
        FROM sql.Companies c2
        WHERE c2.SEGMENT = @Segment
          AND c2.STATE = 'ACTIVE'
    )
    GROUP BY
      c.bid
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) , 1 , LEN(',') , '' )
```

As a side point, if you are concatenating strings which may have XML escaping issues, you would need

```sql
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','varchar(max)') , 1 , LEN(',') , '' )
```

Obviously, in newer versions of SQL Server, you can just use `STRING_AGG`

```sql
 SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('''', c.bid, ''''), ',')
 FROM dbo.Companies c
 WHERE c.IdCompany in (
     SELECT SUBSTRING(c2.ID_COMPANY, 1, LEN(c2.ID_COMPANY) - 2)
     FROM sql.Companies c2
     WHERE c2.SEGMENT = @Segment
       AND c2.STATE = 'ACTIVE'
 )
 GROUP BY
   c.bid
```